# To check if a particular object exists in a vector

Tags: java, object, vector, data-structures

I am creating a vector which stores the object of a particular class. 
This class a String variable which is the identifier of that object.
So, I create an object and set this variable as "abc". Then after this object is destroyed I make another object and set the same variable as "abc".
Now I have to check if there is any object in vector already present with variable set as "abc".

I have tried using toString() and comparable() as such but no success.
I know I can make a loop and check for it but I was hoping for some simpler and faster way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: showing code will be good and also what our friend vec.contains() API says?

Comment: override equals method in your class, and call to vector's contains method.

Comment: That does not work here. It just works for String or some dataTypes not for object.

Comment: *a vector which stores the object of a particular class* it does what now?

Comment: Sry.. my bad.. I didnt try over-riding the equals method..

Comment: @Ankushsoni: Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like…

We have a class Dog.

```
public class Dog {
    public String name;
    public String color;
    public ZonedDateTime dateOfBirth;

    public Dog( String nameArg ) {
        this.name = nameArg;
    }

}
```

We collect instances in a Vector.

```
Vector dogs = new Vector( 3 );
dogs.add( new Dog( "Jupiter" ) ) ;
dogs.add( new Dog( "Jasmine" ) ) ;
dogs.add( new Dog( "Jacques" ) ) ;
```

Later we want to test if the Vector contains any dog by the name of "Jasmine"? Not that particular dog above, but any containing that text as its name?

Yes, looping to ask each dog's name and compare the text returned is one way.

Another way is to override the `equals` method to compare names. Then you can call the `contains` method on the vector to see if it has a matching dog object. But overriding `equals` is often not realistic. In this example, sharing a name does not mean we have the same dog and so we don't want that to be the definition of equals.

## Map

A better approach is to use a different collection than Vector. One of the `Map` implementations makes more sense. A map stores a pair of objects, a key and a value.

In this example the dog's name string would be the key. The dog object would be the value. When you later provide the key, you can retrieve the value (the dog object). You can ask the map if it contains contains a particular key.

See the [Tutorial on Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html).

---

By the way, Vector is generally not used any more. It was long ago supplanted by other implementations of `List` such as `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.